# Search row by average ratings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

There will be ratings for post which user can give,How can I search post by its average rating.

Post model

```
//post model

public function avgRating()
{
    return $this->ratings()->selectRaw('avg(ratings) as avgRatings,post_id')->groupBy('post_id');
}

public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('avgRating', $this->relations)) {
       $this->load('avgRating');
    }
    $relation = $this->getRelation('avgRating')->first();
    return ($relation) ? $relation->avgRatings : null;
}
```

with above code I can get average ratings for each of the post,Now How can I filter posts by ratings like get posts with the average ratings 1 or average ratings 2 or average ratings 3 or average ratings 4 or average ratings 5,

```
 //To filter data
 public function filter()
 {
     $post= (new Post)->newQuery();

     if ($request->has('averageRatings')) {
        $post->whereHas('avgRating', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('rating', $request->input('averageRatings'))->avgRating;
        });
    }
   $results = $institute->get();
 }
```

Comment: use whereIn() clause like whereIn('ratings.ratings',['1','2','3','4','5']);

Comment: ratings.ratings doesn't match what you called the column in your select..  Also, you shouldn't be comparing it exactly, shouldn't you be using a greater than or less than?

Comment: No that did not work.@sunitiyadav